# WhatsApp Web automation for random messages with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, random, automation, whatsapp

**PLEASE SEE THE UPDATE BELOW THIS FIRST MESSAGE**

I'm creating a bot to send random messages from WhatsApp Web.

```
msg_1 = ["Hey, ", "Hello, "]
print(random.choice(msg_1))
```

The code above works fine, but when I use It with `send_keys` In Selenium the result is just the comma and the space.

```
msg_1 = ["Hey, ", "Hello, "]   

campo_msg = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('...')
campo_msg.click()      # Tried with a click to see If It solves the problem
campo_msg.send_keys(random.choice(msg_1))
```

The result Is always ", " in `campo_msg`... If I send just a string with `send_keys` It works fine, so what am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

The problem was that my list was with words that had "á", so It was sending just the following characters after "á".

Using `ActionChains` as PDHide suggested I'm now able to send the correct string with `random.choice()`. The problem Is that sometimes It looks like that It's making clicks on elements that was not supposed to... Here's a example:

```
...
campo_msg = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
campo_msg.click()
    
webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(random.choice(msg_1) + primeiro_nome + '.').perform()
campo_msg.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
campo_msg.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
    
webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(random.choice(msg_2) + random.choice(msg_3)
                                                          + random.choice(msg_4)).perform()
# The line above is were the code makes a click on an element that was not even on the code.
```

It sends the correct key but then It makes the click on a random element.

Comment: msg= random.choice(msg_1) , campo_msg.send_keys(msg) ?

Comment: @PDHide It worked like a charm thank!! What could be wrong? I really did not understand It...

Comment: what happens if you use : campo_msg.send_keys(( random.choice(msg_1)))

Comment: your code works as it is

Comment: @PDHide Sorry, just found the exactly problem but still do not know how to solve It.
In my language we use the signals ´ ^ ~ so when the string have It the code is just ignoring till the comma. I'v just changed the project encoding to UFT-8 but still not working.

Comment: Hello in Portuguese is Olá, so that's why I was having problems.

Answer (score 2):

use actions class instead

```
msg_1 = ["Olá, ", "Hello, "]  
campo_msg.click()  
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(random.choice(msg_1)).perform()
```

Its an interesting question it seems if you send á after any character it is selecting all the other characters. Thats why you are getting only the last character. á selects all and next character replacesthe previous strings. You can verify this by looping through each character of 'olál' with a sleep of 2 sec.

Comment: Thank's PDHide, It worked for sending the whole string.

However, now It's kinda bugging the automation... For some of the `webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(random.choice(...)).perform()` that I'v used the code is clicking on elements that It was not supposed to. I'll update my question with the code snippet and I would be glad If you could help me.